# Search Bank/Credit card account with Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

When i search bank or credit card account by using with Yodlee API: /jsonsdk/SiteTraversal/searchSite

Is it possible to search string with starting match case? Because of when we search bank accounts, it's takes more time to get the response from Yodlee API. It's possible to get result less than 2-3 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee APIs are optimized and should not take this much time, which there might be the cases when you would be providing the very generic keyword in search like bank or credit or america etc. Instead, I would recommend you to provide some specific keywords like Wells Fargo, Bank of America etc, search should reflect the bank's name. Though search inputs can't be controlled as this is used to be entered by consumers. You can add some help text for your consumers saying please provide specific bank names; this will return you response quickly.